# Return null or empty Document in rapidjson

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I've created a helper method that parses a char *. But when something fails I want it to return a null like `Document`. How would I do this for rapidjson? 
For example, In jsoncpp they had `Value::null`.

```
Document & CEJsonHelper::parse(const char * inputString) {
    Document d;
    auto& document = d.Parse(inputString);

    if(document.HasParseError()){
        auto error = "Failed to parse JSON (offset " + std::to_string(d.GetErrorOffset()) + "). "
                "Error: " + GetParseError_En(document.GetParseError());
        Log(error);
        return Document::Null; //wrong
    }

    return document;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Document::Null`? A valid document with no contents?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I would also suggest looking into std::optional or boost::optional if that's accessible to you? I like that pattern for the times that you might not return a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand the request, you can change the last line to

```
return d.Parse("{}");
```

If this code is possibly frequent and the returned document is not intended to be changed (in this case you better change the return value of the function to `const Document&`), you might want to cache the result of the abovementioned expression somewhere in your application, and return it as needed.

**UPDATE:** also, I might be wrong, but later versions of RapidJson (at least current stable 1.1.0) throw an exception on bad document instead of flagging an error variable.

Comment: I never thought of such a simple idea. But does seem like a hack. Thanks!

Comment: "throw an exception on bad document instead of flagging an error variable." Good to know. I'll double check on that one.

Comment: Isn't there another way to create empty object without verbose parsing?